# How to make an array calling functions in another class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a array of functions that will call different sorting functions from my sort class.
The array I'm trying to pass is one from my own array class.

https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/128162-array-functions.html
This website showed how to do it from within the class you are in and without parameters, but I want to call functions from another class using an array. 
Needs to pass a parameter in.

```
//What I want to do
static int (*func[2])() = { Sort.BruteForceBubble, Sort.FlaggedBubble};
func[1](&myArrayCopy); //Too many arguments

//What works 
Sort.BruteForceBubble(&myArrayCopy);
Sort.FlaggedBubble(&myArrayCopy);
```

My goal is to call a loop going through all the functions so I can compare the speeds of them all.

Comment: `static int (*func[2])()` -- Ask yourself what this actually declares.  Do the empty parentheses look right?  Also, please specify the function declaration you're trying to make a pointer of.  The code you're showing only shows how you want to call the function.

Answer (score 2):

```
int (*func[2])()
```

The function pointer you've declared takes no arguments. Declare the functions arg types correctly, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried to set the argument type which should be (Array<int> *a) but it says element type cannot be function or abstract class type

Comment: Would it be easier to make the function in the Sorting class?

Comment: ```int (func[2])(Array<int> * sortArray) = { Sort.BruteForceBubble, Sort.FlaggedBubble};``` ```'func' array element type cannot be function or abstract class type``` that's what I got

Comment: @JasonFarrell You lost `*` in your declaration. You cannot have array of functions. You can have array of pointers to functions

Comment: what R2RT said. 

    int (*func[2])(Array<int> * sortArray)

Comment: Ah that fixed most of it but now I have the error ```'Sorter::BruteForceBubble': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member``` and if I make it ```Sort.BruteForceBubble()``` it says it does not take 0 arguments

Comment: @JasonFarrell -- You really should have all of that information you placed in the answer comments within the original post.  Things such as the declaration of the function you're calling should have been in the original question, not here.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to a case statement made everything much simpler:

```
switch (sortType)
{
case 0:
    Sort.BruteForceBubble(&myArrayCopy);
    break;
case 1:
    Sort.FlaggedBubble(&myArrayCopy);
    break;
}
```

However something like `func[0](&myArrayCopy);` would've been nicer, this is much easier to implement.